# Remove line feeds except the first line

Tags: linux

I would like to create a file where the line feeds are removed, except in the first line.

Input:

```
EHH_2020_A1
CCAAGATATTTTATAT
CCATATACC
ATTAT
GTA
```

Desired output:

```
EHH_2020_A1
CCAAGATATTTTATATCCATATACCATTATGTA
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless 1 == $.' file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line,
- `$.` stores the current line number,
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the final newline (if present)

If you want to keep the final newline, change the condition to

```
unless 1 == $. || eof
```

- [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) returns true when at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it trivially in `awk` as well, e,g, with your input in the file `genes`, you would have:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1 {print; next} {printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' genes
EHH_2020_A1
CCAAGATATTTTATATCCATATACCATTATGTA
```

Where the command takes the first record (line) where `FNR==1` and simply prints it unchanged. The second rule prints all other lines without a `'\n'` effectively concatenating them together, and the `END` rule outputs the final newline.